# Simulate real time data visualization using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I am creating a POC, where real time update will reflect on my shiny application. The idea is to plot the frequency distribution of the data that is being generated from a server. Since I do not have access to the server yet, I have simulated a data creation which I am feeding to my plot. I can see the data properly on my console, but nothing is being displayed on my application. I am sure that there is something I am missing out. I think the reason I am unable to view the plot is because the data is getting updated faster than the rendering speed. Is there any way to modify that.

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)


ui <- shinyServer(fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
))


alarms = c("NodeDown","GrowthRate","DecayRate","DiskFull","ServiceDown","Planned_shutdown","etc.....etc","ServerOutage",
           "No Casue")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  # Function to get new observations
  get_new_data <- function(){

    new = sample(alarms,1)
#    data <- new %>% rbind %>% data.frame
    return(new)
  }

  # Initialize my_data
  my_data <<- get_new_data()

  # Function to update my_data
  update_data <- function(){
    my_data <<- c(get_new_data(), my_data)

  }

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    update_data()
#    print(my_data)
    dd = update_data()
    dd = as.data.frame(table(dd))
    print(dd)
    plot_ly(dd, x = ~dd, y = ~Freq)
  })

  # Plot the 30 most recent values
#  output$first_column <- renderPlot({
#    print("Render")
#    invalidateLater(1000, session)
#    update_data()
#    print(my_data)
#    plot(X1 ~ 1, data=my_data[1:30,], ylim=c(-3, 3), las=1, type="l")
#  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `reactiveValues` to append your vector, and use `reactiveTimer` with `observeEvent` to trigger it every second

Also, if you want to use `renderPlotly` in `server`, you should use `plotlyOutput` rather than `plotOutput` in `ui`

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)


ui <- shinyServer(fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
))


alarms = c("NodeDown","GrowthRate","DecayRate","DiskFull","ServiceDown","Planned_shutdown","etc.....etc","ServerOutage",
           "No Casue")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  get_new_data <- function(){
    new = sample(alarms,1)
    return(new)
  }

  my_data <-reactiveValues(data=get_new_data())

  observeEvent(reactiveTimer(2000)(),{ # Trigger every 2 seconds
    my_data$data<-c(get_new_data(),my_data$data)
    print(my_data$data)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    dd=as.data.frame(table(my_data$data))
    print(dd)
    plot_ly(dd, x = ~Var1, y = ~Freq)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```